# Sum Char Columns until Count Reached

Tags: sas

I have a table that looks something like this (with more records and more notes):

```
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+
|id    |note_1         |len_1 |note_2         |len_2 |note_3         |len_3 |  
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+
|10001 |"abcde"        |5     |"abc"          |3     |"abcdefg"      |7     |  
|10002 |"defghijk"     |8     |"ghuio"        |5     |"yuio"         |4     | 
|10003 |"abc"          |3     |"defg"         |4     |"qw"           |2     | 
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+
```

and I'd like to create a do loop in a SAS `data` step that concatenates all of the notes until a certain length is reached (in this example, length of 10). Here's the ideal column that would be created for this example, given a max of 10:

```
+------+--------------+
|id    |concat_notes  |
+------+--------------+
|10001 |"abcdeabcab"  |
|10002 |"defghijkgh"  |
|10003 |"abcdefgqw"   |
+------+--------------+
```

Here's the code I'm trying to create:

```
data length;
set notes;
concats = "";
do i=1 to 3;
    if (vvaluex(cats("len_",i)) > 10) then concat_notes= concats;
    else concats = cats(concats,vvaluex(cats("note_",i)));
end;
run;
```

Note: In reality, all the notes are very long and my max length is 32767. I can't concatenate them all and use `substrn` to take the first 32,767 because of space issues.

Comment: Why are you using `vvaluex()`? Note that SAS will just truncate the value automatically.  Are you trying to avoid notes in the log?

Comment: @Tom That confused me too originally - notice that they're using it to indirectly access the variables, though, in an array-like fashion without actually coding an array.  I'm not sure why they're avoiding the array, though, who knows...

Comment: I was originally using `CATX` to combine the variables but a warning would appear from SAS in the log and it would end up leaving the result completely blank. Only using vvaluex() because I'm a novice to SAS and I'm not sure the best way to reference a column in a loop. 

The warning: "In a call to the CATX function, the buffer allocated for the result was not long enough...The correct result would contain 35942 characters, but the actual result might either be truncated ... or be completely blank, depending on the calling environment. "

Comment: What should happen if an intermediate note would take you over the limit, and a subsequent one wouldn't ? Should the concatenating end at the 'limit-busting' test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can just check the lengths directly:

```
%let max_length=10;
data have;
input id note_1 $ len_1 note_2 $ len_2 note_3 $ len_3;
datalines;
  10001    abcde           5        abc             3        abcdefg         7         
  10002    defghijk        8        ghuio           5        yuio            4        
  10003    abc             3        defg            4        qw              2        
;;;;
run;
data want;
  set have;
  array notes note_:;
  length cat_note $10;
  do _i = 1 to dim(notes);
    if length(cat_note) + length(notes[_i]) le &max_length. then 
        cat_note = cats(cat_note,notes[_i]);
    else if length(cat_note) lt &max_length. then 
        cat_note = cats(cat_note, substr(notes[_i],1,(&max_length.-length(cat_note))));  *added to get last bit;
  end;
  keep id cat_note;
run;
```

You can just directly add the length also, if there's a reason you don't want to use the `length` function to check the lengths, but this seems fine performance-wise...  don't go through that vvaluex stuff though, that doesn't really make sense.  Just create a summation variable and every time you concat something, add to it.

Remember length() for character variables returns the length up to the last non-space character, so this accurately reflects what you're looking for.

Edited to add in the leftover to get to 10 exactly.

Answer (score 6):

The stated actual max length is 32,767, which is also the max length of SAS character variables.  Thus, you might want a blithe concatenation of the desired variables and let normal truncation occur if the result would exceed 32K characters.

Robust code will use a `length` statement to specify how much space to allocate for the variable storing the resultant.

```
set notes;
length notes_catted $32767;
notes_catted = cats (of note_:);
```

Non-robust

```
set notes;
notes_catted = cats (of note_:);  * variable will be given implicit default length $200;
```

When length is not specified the DATA Step compiler will choose to create a variable of length $200 instead.  From the help file:

> **Length of Returned Variable**
> In a DATA step, if the CATS function returns a value to a variable that has not previously been assigned a length, then that variable is given a length of 200 bytes. *Additionally (my italics)*, If the concatenation operator (||) returns a value to a variable that has not previously been assigned a length, then that variable is given a length that is the sum of the lengths of the values that are being concatenated.